# Excel pivot table recursive hierarchy

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

This is my input data (sample)

[image: Input Data]

Excel pivot table currently gives me this

[image: Pivot Table Output]

However I want an output like this

[image: What I need]

Can pivot table be configured to give that output?
Or is there any other tool I can use to get it?

I want to get this done without any coding.

Comment: Either I don't understand, or the answer is definitely "no" - because you only have qty 15000 worth of records for which [Lvl2] is `D`, so there's no way to pivot that data to have 15000 add up to 25000.

Comment: Excel pivot tables don't support recursive hierarchies. You will need to restructure the data to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yup, pivots won't work. Indeed you need restructure the data. Ps. are you calculating Multi-level-markting company profist or just a normal pyramid scheme? :)

Comment: Why E only 10000 but not 25000? Could you provide the output condition？

Comment: @Lee C and E are children of D, call children add up and go to the parent. From Original data Lvl1 is child and Lvl2 is parent.

Comment: @Mobus I don't know what its called, jargon unknow, I want to add up the child figures and that should end up in the parent. So parent should get all immediate and deep childrens total figures.

Comment: @AlexM yeah its kinda recursive, I  don't mind using any other tool, as long as I don't need to code.

Comment: @FlexYourData do any other tools support recursive hierarchies. What do I need to do to restructure the data, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can arrange your data like this (staggered, level by level):

[image]

Lastly fill up like this:

[image]

Then a PIVOT can help (levels go right to left into rows):

[image]

[image]

Not sure who to get rid of the blanks though... maybe ="" or fill to the left (copy cell to the right if blank into all blanks to the left e.g. bottom row would be `e e e d`)

Comment: Thanks! sorry cannot upvote due to lack of reputation.